# tinymce noneditable contents not working properly

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinyMCE editor, i need to make some contents radonly (nonEditable).

As per its documentation, if i use class "mceNonEditable" with some elements, it fulfill the requirement, but unfortunately if i select that specific element and press backspace / Enter / Delete button, it removes that content.

All i want is that, user shouldn't be able to make any contact with those elements.

Official example can be seen [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/noneditable_content.php).

Any how, I also tried to accomplish this with an overlay div, overlay div needs absolute position, and after applying this style, editor convert this div into drag able form.

Please help, if there is any other solution..

[image: Here is the screenshot attached]

Comment: I would go with another approach. On load replace your non editable content with a placeholder. Store the non-editable code in some session variable. On submit validate if the placeholder is still there. If the placeholder is gone, raise an error and let the user insert a new placeholder (via insert menu or a button). If the placeholder exists, replace it with the stored non editable content. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that setting the `contentEditable` attribute to `false` on the element does the trick.